# Word/phrase for remarks which often have a dark feel to them but whose meanings are not readily apparent?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, american-english

I know someone who has a tendency to make strange remarks whose meanings are not readily apparent, remarks which often have a dark feel to them, but which are left unexplained, as if to hide something. I’m seeking a word or phrase for these type of remarks. Any suggestions?

Edit: So think of it this way. You having a seemingly conversation with someone, and the person says something offkey that makes you think "hmm, where'd that come from? That was kind of dark."

Comment: I'm struggling with the wording of your question; can you give an example?

Comment: Why is this tagged "american-english"?

Comment: I believe the word is _speaking_. We don’t usually explain what we say, because normally the listener understands our words and doesn’t need an explanation.

Answer (score 4):

The verb you want is insinuate.

(from google)  - suggest or hint (something bad or reprehensible) in an indirect and unpleasant way.

Answer (score 3):

You might be looking for ***opaque*** or ***abstruse***

From *The Free Dictionary*:

> [*opaque*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/opaque) : 3a. So obscure as to be unintelligible
>
> [*abstruse*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/abstruse) : Difficult to understand; recondite: *The students avoided the professor's abstruse lectures.*

Answer (score 2):

Since you mention that, "**It usually has a dark connotation**..." I'd suggest:

> **Cryptic**: adjective \ˈkrip-tik\
>
> **1**: secret, occult, obscure
>
> **2** **a**: having or seeming to have a hidden or ambiguous meaning: mysterious. cryptic messages b: marked by an often perplexing brevity, cryptic marginal notes
>
> **3**: serving to conceal, cryptic coloration in animals; also: exhibiting cryptic coloration, cryptic animals
>
> **4**: not recognized, a cryptic infection
>
> **5**: employing cipher or code—cryp•ti•cal•ly adverb
>
> **Examples of CRYPTIC**
>
> His instructions were cryptic. He said only to wait until we felt certain the answer was clear, puzzled by the cryptic e-mail message left on his computer. “… his hectic characters either communicate in choppy or cryptic exchanges or rattle on in breathless recitations full of contradictions and asides.” —-Donna Seaman, Booklist, 15 Mar. 1994
>
> **Origin of CRYPTIC**
>
> Late Latin *crypticus*, from Greek *kryptikos*, from *kryptos*. First Known Use: *circa* 1638
>
> **Related to CRYPTIC**
>
> **Synonyms**: arcane, mysterious, deep, enigmatic (also, enigmatical), impenetrable, inscrutable, mystic, occult, uncanny. **Antonyms**: accessible, clear, nonambiguous, obvious, plain, unambiguous, unequivocal.

[merriam-webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cryptic)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are thinking of **innuendo,** which Oxforddictionaries.com defines [as follows:](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/innuendo)

> NOUN (plural *innuendoes* or *innuendos*)
>
> An allusive or oblique remark or hint, typically a suggestive or disparaging one:
>
> *she’s always making sly **innuendoes***
>
> *a constant torrent of **innuendo**, gossip, lies, and half-truths*

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to think of "allude"? (To refer to something indirectly) It isn't necessarily *dark*, but it coveys a certain amount of mystery.

Answer (score 0):

You may be thinking of

> **condescending**

Another possibility is simply

> **deceptive**

Comment: _Condescending_ means something completely different from what the OP is asking about.

Answer (score 0):

[Obscure](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/obscure):

> - Not clearly understood or expressed; ambiguous or vague: Some say that Blake's style is obscure and complex.

(from TFD)

Comment: Ominous. Or "vaguely ominous"

Answer (score 0):

**Talking in riddles** is often used

> talk in riddles:
>
> to talk in a way that is difficult to understand

[[Cambridge Idioms Dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/talk+in+riddles)]

If it must be a single word,

**obscurantism**

> n.
>   2. deliberate obscurity or evasion of clarity.

[[R H K Webster's](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/obscurantism)] fits, but is (a) a less precise fit and (b) hardly colloquial.